# Advantage of Using NVL over OR in a Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have the Table below:

```
create table xxnvloror
(   XX_ID       NUMBER
,   ITEM        VARCHAR2(100)
,   AMOUNT      NUMBER
);
```

And I inserted 10000 records into it, putting some `NULL` values in the Amounts:

```
Declare 

    l_amount number;

BEGIN

    for i in 1..10000 loop

        if mod(i, 2) = 0 then

            l_amount := null;

        else

            l_amount := i;

        end if;

        insert into xxnvloror
        (   XX_ID  
        ,   ITEM   
        ,   AMOUNT 
        )
        VALUES
        (
            i
        ,   'item-'||i
        ,   l_amount
        );  

    end loop;

END;
```

I used the 2 queries below:

```
select  *
from    xxnvloror
where   amount is null or amount = 0;

select  *
from    xxnvloror
where   nvl(amount, 0) = 0;
```

I checked their Explain Plans and they don't seem to matter than much:

```
Plan hash value: 1982466860

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |  5000 | 80000 | 15087   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXNVLOROR |  5000 | 80000 | 15087   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("AMOUNT" IS NULL OR "AMOUNT"=0)

Plan hash value: 1982466860

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |  5001 | 80016 | 15088   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXNVLOROR |  5001 | 80016 | 15088   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(NVL("AMOUNT",0)=0)
```

Without any Indexes, are there any advantages of Using `NVL` over `OR`, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the asbence of indexes there will be no difference in resource usage, I/O, or performance.

Without any indexes, the engine will perform a Full Table Scan. It will read all rows from the heap and compute the predicate value to decide if it will keep or discard each row. The CPU usage difference is marginal between both predicates.

Additionally, your predicate is not selective enough. It selects around 50% of the table. In this case a Full Table Scan is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a query like this:

```
where amount is null or amount = 0
```

can make use of an index on `amount`.  Hence, this formulation is usually preferable.

I should add that Oracle supports function-based indexes.  So, if you have an index on `nvl(amount, 0)`, then `where nvl(amount, 0) = 0` would be preferable.